# Delete specific items in a list based on numbers in another list in R

Tags: r, list, element

I have two lists, one containing varying lengths of character values (dat) and the other with a single numeric value in each element (delete_n).

```
dat <- list(c("Apple", "Pear"), c("Red", "Blue", "Green"), c("Toyota", "Mazda"))
delete_n <- list(0, 2, 1)
```

The elements in the "delete_n" pair up with the elements in "dat" (delete_n[1] goes with dat[1], and so on).  The "delete_n" numbers (0,2,1) tell me how many specific list items in each element I need to delete from the end of each row.

Based on the example, I'm looking for a solution that will delete 0 items from dat[1], delete "Blue" and "Green" from dat[2] and "Mazda" from dat[3].

I've tried first to match up the element numbers and then to identify the element list index by the variations of the following, with no success.  mapply may be more appropriate, but again I'm unclear as to how to write the function() portion.

```
lapply(seq_along(dat), function(x) {
    sapply(seq_along(delete_n), function(y) {
        x[y]
    })
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mapply(function (x, n) {
    # x is an element of dat; n is an element of delete_n
    x[seq_len(length(x)-n)]
}, dat, delete_n)
```

Explanation:

`mapply` applies the function to each element of `dat` and `delete_n`, taken together (so all first elements, all second elements, etc).

`seq_len(i)` makes the vector `1:i`, so `seq_len(length(x)-n)` selects all but the last `n` elements of `x`.

Comment: Variation on a theme: `Map(function(d,n) if(n==0) d else head(d,-n), dat, delete_n)`

Comment: @thelatemail I also initially went with `head(d, -n)` but if n=0 it fails (returns 0-length).

Comment: Using negative zeros in `tail` and `head` didn't work as I expected either. I don't think it can read our minds since ` (-0) == 0 #[1] TRUE`

Comment: Jiggery pokery, indeed. Did'ja see John Oliver's take on that phrase? Priceless.

Comment: All workable solutions, thank you.  mapply with seq_len seems the most straightforward to me though.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just because I couldn't let this go without making `head` work:
If you change `delete_n` to a vector `c(0,2,1)` (which it could easily be since there is only one value for each corresponding `dat` list item), you can do:

```
Map(head, dat, n=-replace(delete_n, delete_n==0, -Inf))
```

Answer (score 3):

I liked the mapply approach, but this was what seemed natural to me (after failing with negative zeroes anyway).

```
 mapply( head, dat, sapply(dat, length )- unlist(delete_n ))
#-------
[[1]]
[1] "Apple" "Pear" 

[[2]]
[1] "Red"

[[3]]
[1] "Toyota"
```

Comment: In up-to-date R, you could replace `sapply(dat,length)` with `lengths(dat)` too.